# Cortana from Win32

Tags: c++, windows, windows-runtime, native

This is a rather directionless post I'm afraid an I apologize. I'm trying to figure out how to use Cortana from win32 (non universal) applications. I found [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.voicecommands.voicecommanddefinitionmanager.installcommanddefinitionsfromstoragefileasync.aspx) but I can't tell if there is a way to access these APIs from non-managed code.  That sent me on a rabbit trail to find out what this UniversalApiContract stuff is and how to use it form native code but so far I am coming up very empty.

Could someone please provide me with some direction!! What do I even need to search for to begin to learn how to access these APIs natively? Is there some reading on windows runtime that I should undertake?

Thanks in advance and again I apologize for the general questions - not sure where else to turn.

Comment: I'll also take a link to a forum or a better location to ask such an open question. If this gets closed I at least ask for that :)

Comment: Does [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/10/02/using-windows-8-winrt-apis-in-net-desktop-applications.aspx) point you in the right direction? What you are trying should be possible.

Comment: That seems to be about using them from C# not unmanaged C++

Comment: Try using COM? LoadLibrary: Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.dll or Windows.ApplicationModel.dll and then call DLLGetClassObject or something.. I'm not too sure but that seems like the way to go..

Comment: Searching the windows SDK for CLSID_VoiceCommandDefinitionManager returns nothing, not sure how id query for it. Same for IID. Theres no interface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Expressed displeasure over how many people voted to close the thread without any useful response or suggestions]

Now, on to science.
After spending some time with this it would seem this is not possible.  **I was able to call the API from Win32** by using the [Visual C++ Component Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699871.aspx). This allows you to use windows runtime and CLR like concepts but results in purely native code.  As a side note, since I wanted to link this with an application that I did not want to recompile with this extension, I did this in a DLL and delay loaded it.

Unfortunately [the call to install the voice command definition file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.voicecommands.voicecommanddefinitionmanager.installcommanddefinitionsfromstoragefileasync.aspx) failed with a COMException: The process has no package identity.  This means I can successfully call the API, however **it requires a package identity** - in other words, it must be called from a Modern/Store/Universal App context with an application identity.

The only way remaining to me seems to be to use the Cortana background API to interface with a modern app I write in the background, and use it to broker calls from my Win32 app to Cortana through some sort of custom communication. Icky.

I hope this helps save someone else time.

Comment: could you please post your code snippet where you are able to do it? I think I will be OK if I compile my stuff with the extension you have specified. Thank you so much!